# How do I populate a json array in a given column directly in Controller methods?

Tags: php, laravel

In my two methods `store()` and `update()`, I want to use `properties` which is a nullable JSON array to directly store all the information from other migration columns. Apparently, the code is just not doing the expected action of populating `properties`.

#### Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('hunters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name_hunter', 50);
        $table->integer('year_hunter');
        $table->decimal('height_hunter', 3,2);
        $table->decimal('weight_hunter', 5,2);
        $table->string('type_hunter', 30);
        $table->string('type_nen', 30);
        $table->string('type_sangue', 3);
        $table->timestamp('register_date')->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp('data_updated')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
        $table->json('properties')->nullable();
    });
}
```

#### `Hunter` Model

```php
protected $fillable = ['name_hunter', 'year_hunter', 'height_hunter', 'weight_hunter', 'type_hunter', 'type_nen', 'type_blood'];

protected $casts = [
    'properties' => 'array'
];
```

#### `Hunter` Controller

```
public function store(HunterRequest $request)
{
    $hunter = new HunterModel();
    $validations = $request->validated();
    $hunter['properties'] = json_encode($validations);

    HunterModel::create($validations);

    return redirect('/'); 
}

public function update(HunterRequest $request, $id)
{
    $hunter = HunterModel::find($id);
    $validations = $request->validated();
    $hunter['properties'] = json_encode($validations);

    HunterModel::where('id',$id)->update($validations);

    return redirect('/');  
}
```

When using `dd($hunter)` both `store()` and `update()` return values, but it doesn't save in the properties column in the database.

Comment: you ain't creating from the ``$hunter``!!

Comment: ```HunterModel::create($validations, $hunter);``` and ```HunterModel::where('id',$id)->update($validations);``` don't work.

Comment: Since you are using the `array` cast then you don't need to JSON encode the data yourself

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `$validations` variable instead of the `$hunter` variable.

```
public function store(HunterRequest $request)
{
    ...
    HunterModel::create($hunter);
    ...
}

public function update(HunterRequest $request, $id)
{
    ...
    HunterModel::where('id', $id)->update($hunter);
    ... 
}
```